# How to mock external function call in jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking

I want to test this function using jest. here is my code-

templeate.ts

```
export const generateSalamWelcome = async function (
      actionSource: IActionSource,
      actionDetails: IActionDetails
    ): Promise<IReplyTemplate[] | undefined> {
      try {
        const { pageId } = actionSource;
        const { actionExt } = actionDetails;
        const restaurantData = await getRestaurantQueriesMultiple(pageId, []);
        if (restaurantData) {
          const replyTemplates: IReplyTemplate[] = [];
          const { enOnly, bnOnly } = restaurantData;
          const mode = getMode(enOnly, bnOnly, actionExt || languageModes.EN);
          replyTemplates.push(
            generateTextTemplate(
              selectTextEnBn(mode, strings.salamWelcomeEn, strings.salamWelcomeBn)
            )
          );
          return replyTemplates;
        }
      } catch (err) {
        logger.error(err);
      }
    };
```

I want to mock getRestaurantQueriesMultiple, getMode and generateTextTemplate functions.  How do I mock them properly to return some dummy result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `mockImplementation()` in jest. With this you can `spyOn()` on a class method or a function in a file. For example in your case, let's consider a filename `MyFile.ts` in which you have exported the function `getMode()`. If your `getMode()` exists in the same file `template.ts` then dont consider file name as `MyFile`, instead go with `template.ts`. So, inside your `it` block you could do something like this,

```
const dummyResult = 'dummyData';

jest.spyOn(MyFile, 'getMode')
  .mockImplementation(() => {
    return Promise.resolve(dummyResult);
  })
```

Similarly you can do the same for `getRestaurantQueriesMultiple()` and `generateTextTemplate()`. But make sure you mock all these functions before you make a call to the actual function, which in your case is `generateSalamWelcome()`

You can read more about `mockImplementation()` here [Jest Mock Implementation](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockimplementationfn)